# How can I print 1 inch grid into an actual size

Tags: grids, ppi, digital-printing

I am struggling to print out 1 inches square grid on A4-paper. The squares comes out about 1,8 inches.

I have tried on 2 different printers (Brothers DCP-L5500DN Laser printer, and a Epson ET-2820 inkjet). I also tried printing out different grids from Internet, and simple squares with Google Draw document.

When I print I made sure to set size to actual size, no paper margins, and used 300 PPI.

Comment: Why don't you just scale it to 1.8 times smaller and print again? Are you printing directly from the browser or using any graphic software?

Comment: I tried printing with Gimp, Windows Photo and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I am not sure why scaling it to 1.8 would solve it?

Comment: In your print dialog, make sure you do not have "fit to page" selected, instead choose scaling as none/100%

Comment: It won't solve it _per se_ but you'll get your grid printed in the correct scale in the meantime.

Comment: I can´t t see an options "fit to page". But I tried both Actual size and and size to 100%.

Comment: This particular task is actually much trickyer than one owuld think it is. Pinters are very far form perfect machines. But here is a tip. It is much much easier to do this in a vector drawing file as it does not suffer form interpolation defiencies. It is less of a hit an miss than a raster image. SO switch over to inkscape (or illustrator or corel) draw the grid. But thsi is not enough: Ive done mm grid graphing paper in the past and it gets hairy, you need to redraw the thing after you have printed since your printer is probably off by a bit so you need to compensate for line with aliasing.

Comment: Yeah different printers have different options, depends on the print driver what options are available, or what the options are actually called. There definitely has to be some scaling going on. Not sure it's really possible to answer this definitively without access to your computer and printer set up. Another thing to check is if you have borderless printing selected, because that can also mess up scaling, since some printers will actually enlarge an image slightly so that it goes over the edge of the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to turn off borderless printing. I wonder if more then I get the same problem. Can it be replicated?
@joojaa - When I get more time I try vector programs. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: old post, but "borderless printing" is code for "upscale the image" in most drivers: the image is assumed to be smaller than the sheet and the driver will scale it up to print *past* the edges of the paper. This simulates a pre-set bleed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Google Draw is the correct tool for this. I have just made a Document, and the only sizing options are proportions, not real dimensions.

[image]

I recommend you to use the proper software. Use Inkscape which is free.

Comment: I get the same issue when producing 1 inch square with Inkscape.